# java: activating a mouse click event

Tags: java, mouseevent

I have a java method activated by a mouse click on a button

```
 private void backButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { do stuff }
```

is there some way to virtually use this method from another method without clicking the mouse on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can just use button.doClick();

Comment: I can see the button being clicked programatically but the function it is supposed to perform does not happen. When I click it with the mouse it does function? what am I missing?

Comment: Don't know. You must not have the proper reference to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [MouseEvent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) has public constructors, so you simply create one, and call the function with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can say backButtonMouseClicked(new MouseEvent()) to call the method. Or maybe backButtonMouseClicked(null).